# Trouble with Additional Include Directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

In visual studio community 2017 project I need to include a header, located at:

C:\openssl-lib\include\openssl\x509.h

I've added the path C:\openssl-lib\include under:

Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories

Then i try to include it:

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>
```

and receive an error that i cannot:

RC1015 cannot open include file 'openssl/x509.h'

I cannot understand why that happens. Even when I type the include in the source file visual studio suggests the header at its proper location.
I've tried the following:

1) Change <> to "". No difference

2) change "/" to "\" or the opposite. Again no difference.

3) Added the additional include directory in both Release and Debug and compiled in both - no effect.

4) Adding "C:\openssl-lib\include;" under Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories . That works and fixes the problem, however why does that work and the additional directories not? This should not be the solution.

What causes this?

Edit 1:

5) enter the full direcory path in the additional directories 
C:\openssl-lib\include\openssl. No effect.

Edit 2:

**Solution**

Thanks to Hans and Phil, the reason for this behavior is because RC1015 is a resource error and the additional directory should be added to the resource compiler at Project > Properties > Resources > General,

Comment: Check configuration (Win32/x64) too. And in Project properties > C/C++ > Command Line you see the complete parameters. Is there an `/I"C:\openssl-lib\include"`?

Comment: Hello, i have only Win32. For the command line - yes there is a line /I"C:\openssl-lib\include".

Comment: `RC1015` is a resource compiler error.  Are you including this as part of a resource file?

Comment: Actually yes. But how does that affect anything?

Comment: The resource compiler has its own settings.  Project > Properties > Resources > General, Additional Include Directories setting.

Comment: Hey, that was the reason. Could you please post this as a solution so i can give you credit?